# How to create new rows by selected row value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two datasets need to join and one of them needs to modify in R.

The dataset looks like this:

```
    age_min    age_max    female   male   ID  value      date
      18         24         0       1     10   324    2018-02-05
      18         24         1       0     10   241    2018-02-05
      18         24         1       1     10   152    2018-02-05
      25         34         0       1     10   672    2018-02-05
      25         34         1       0     10   580    2018-02-05
      25         34         1       1     10   439    2018-02-05
      35         44         0       1     10   523    2018-02-05
      35         44         1       0     10   574    2018-02-05
      35         44         1       1     10   678    2018-02-05
      45         54         0       1     10   127    2018-02-05
      45         54         1       0     10   756    2018-02-05
      45         54         1       1     10   273    2018-02-05
      55         64         0       1     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      55         64         1       0     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      55         64         1       1     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      65+        NA         0       1     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      65+        NA         1       0     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      65+        NA         1       1     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      18         24         0       1     10   123    2018-02-06
      18         24         1       0     10   641    2018-02-06
      18         24         1       1     10   901    2018-02-06
      25         34         0       1     10   671    2018-02-06
      25         34         1       0     10   421    2018-02-06
      25         34         1       1     10   784    2018-02-06
      35         44         0       1     10   856    2018-02-06
      35         44         1       0     10   976    2018-02-06
      35         44         1       1     10  1243    2018-02-06
      45         54         0       1     10   745    2018-02-06
      45         54         1       0     10   929    2018-02-06
      45         54         1       1     10   781    2018-02-06
      55         64         0       1     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      55         64         1       0     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      55         64         1       1     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      65+        NA         0       1     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      65+        NA         1       0     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      65+        NA         1       1     10   xxx    2018-02-06
```

There are many different ID and date, the output I want to get looks like this:

```
    age_min    age_max    female   male   ID  value      date
      18         24         0       1     10   324    2018-02-05
      18         24         1       0     10   241    2018-02-05
      18         24         1       1     10   152    2018-02-05
      25         34         0       1     10   672    2018-02-05
      25         34         1       0     10   580    2018-02-05
      25         34         1       1     10   439    2018-02-05
      35         44         0       1     10   523    2018-02-05
      35         44         1       0     10   574    2018-02-05
      35         44         1       1     10   678    2018-02-05
      45         54         0       1     10   127    2018-02-05
      45         54         1       0     10   756    2018-02-05
      45         54         1       1     10   273    2018-02-05
      55         64         0       1     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      55         64         1       0     10   xxx    2018-02-05
      55         64         1       1     10   xxx    2018-02-05
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
add   18         34         0       1     10   996    2018-02-05
      18         34         1       0     10   821    2018-02-05
      18         34         1       1     10   591    2018-02-05 
      18         44         0       1     10  1519    2018-02-05
      18         44         1       0     10  1395    2018-02-05
      18         44         1       1     10  1269    2018-02-05
      18         54         0       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-05
      18         54         1       0     10  xxxx    2018-02-05
      18         54         1       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-05
      18         65+        0       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-05
      18         65+        1       0     10  xxxx    2018-02-05
      18         65+        1       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-05
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      18         24         0       1     10   123    2018-02-06
      18         24         1       0     10   641    2018-02-06
      18         24         1       1     10   901    2018-02-06
      25         34         0       1     10   671    2018-02-06
      25         34         1       0     10   421    2018-02-06
      25         34         1       1     10   784    2018-02-06
      35         44         0       1     10   856    2018-02-06
      35         44         1       0     10   976    2018-02-06
      35         44         1       1     10  1243    2018-02-06
      45         54         0       1     10   745    2018-02-06
      45         54         1       0     10   929    2018-02-06
      45         54         1       1     10   781    2018-02-06
      55         64         0       1     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      55         64         1       0     10   xxx    2018-02-06
      55         64         1       1     10   xxx    2018-02-06
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
add   18         34         0       1     10   794    2018-02-06
      18         34         1       0     10  1062    2018-02-06
      18         34         1       1     10  1685    2018-02-06
      18         44         0       1     10  1650    2018-02-06
      18         44         1       0     10  2038    2018-02-06
      18         44         1       1     10  2928    2018-02-06
      18         54         0       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-06
      18         54         1       0     10  xxxx    2018-02-06
      18         54         1       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-06
      18         65+        0       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-06
      18         65+        1       0     10  xxxx    2018-02-06
      18         65+        1       1     10  xxxx    2018-02-06
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This example is from one ID and there are other ID exist.

I want to sum the value of row 18-24 and 25-34 to create a new row 18-34, sum the value of row 18-24, 25-34, 35-44 to create a row 18-44, repeat the similar step to get 18-54, 18-65+.

I have achieved what I want through the code provided by Jon Spring. The problem is the code value=sum(value) will sum up values from all age group. To solve that problem I removed the age group which I don't want to sum up and compute the total value for 18-34, 18-44, 18-54, 18-65+. Much appreciate for your help, Jon!

Comment: I still without understand what do you want to achieve :(

Comment: I don't see any change in the second frame

Comment: @KenrySanchez -  As far as I can tell it's summing `value` in row 1 and matching row 4, then 2 and 5, then 3 and 6 where `female/male/id/date` match.

Comment: awwww I got it. Ok, leave me to try if I can give you a solution. I think I have done this before in my r studio.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_summary <- df %>%
  group_by(female, male, ID, date) %>%
  summarize(age_min = min(age_min),
            age_max = max(age_max),
            value   = sum(value))
df %>% 
  bind_rows(df_summary) %>%
  arrange(date)   # Edit to sort by date
```

Here's the output, which seems to match the updated OP:

```
   age_min age_max female male ID value       date
1       18      24      0    1 10   324 2018-02-05
2       18      24      1    0 10   241 2018-02-05
3       18      24      1    1 10   152 2018-02-05
4       25      34      0    1 10   672 2018-02-05
5       25      34      1    0 10   580 2018-02-05
6       25      34      1    1 10   439 2018-02-05
7       18      34      0    1 10   996 2018-02-05
8       18      34      1    0 10   821 2018-02-05
9       18      34      1    1 10   591 2018-02-05
10      18      24      0    1 10   123 2018-02-06
11      18      24      1    0 10   641 2018-02-06
12      18      24      1    1 10   901 2018-02-06
13      25      34      0    1 10   671 2018-02-06
14      25      34      1    0 10   421 2018-02-06
15      25      34      1    1 10   784 2018-02-06
16      18      34      0    1 10   794 2018-02-06
17      18      34      1    0 10  1062 2018-02-06
18      18      34      1    1 10  1685 2018-02-06
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I have tried your code and it works in some way. I want to know how to sum the value by date if I have other data? For example, one-year daily value?

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you mean. To add sums for every `date` in a year, you could change `group_by(female, male, ID, date) %>%` to `group_by(female, male, ID, date = lubridate::floor(date, "1 year")) %>%`...

Comment: Hi Jon, I updated my question and probably you can understand my problem better

Comment: Updated with new output, only change was to arrange by date. Seems to match desired output.

Comment: Wow cool, so how to choose the age range if I have other age range like 35-44, 45-54, 55-64? I mean maybe not use min(age_min) and max(age_max)

Comment: Updated again, so how to achieve this output now?

Comment: This seems like you are changing the question beyond the original bounds, which is frustrating from the POV of an answerer. The first two versions seemed fully specified, where the summation rows covered all available ages. In the v3 version of your question, it looks like your desired output excludes data above age 44, and adds one summation for 18-34 and another summation for 18-44. But that goal isn't described anywhere, so I'm not sure if that's specifically what you want. I will wait until the question is fully specified before editing again.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question. I have posted all the age range I have and the desired output shows below. Actually, the code you provided is really helpful but the "value=sum(value)" sums values from all age groups instead of 18-24 and 25-34. That's the main problem I have now.

Comment: To reduce ambiguity, please describe in your question what you want to happen that would get from A to B, beyond just showing B.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've got what I want through your code! Much appreciate your timely help! Also, I put the method I used on the question block!

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate then bind the rows on to the bottom. Here's an attempt in *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
rbind(
  dat,
  dat[,
    .(age_min=min(age_min), age_max=max(age_max), value=sum(value)),
    by=.(female,male,ID,date)]
)
#   age_min age_max female male ID value       date
#1:      18      24      0    1 10   324 2018-02-05
#2:      18      24      1    0 10   241 2018-02-05
#3:      18      24      1    1 10   152 2018-02-05
#4:      25      34      0    1 10   672 2018-02-05
#5:      25      34      1    0 10   580 2018-02-05
#6:      25      34      1    1 10   439 2018-02-05
#7:      18      34      0    1 10   996 2018-02-05
#8:      18      34      1    0 10   821 2018-02-05
#9:      18      34      1    1 10   591 2018-02-05
```

Comment: Hi thelatemail, I tried your code and it produced a value for each ID per day. However, if I changed the age_min and age_max to a specific number like age_min=18, age_max=34. The output value is not true, in fact, the age_min and age_max didn't change the output value. So what should I do if I want to choose the age group manually?